# como crear un campo de un formulario en symfony que me permita obtener un objeto del identificador que venga en la peticion?

Tags: symfony2, doctrine

Buen dia,

Mi pregunta es como crear un campo de un formulario en symfony que me permita obtener un objeto del id que venga en la peticion?, sin que me muestre el error de que "no hay campos extra".

Esto se debe a que me envian en un parametro (y el unico parametro) el id en la peticion, lo que necesito hacer es un campo que convierta lo que viene en ese id a una entidad (ya que asi esta mapeada, no como un entero sino como una entidad).

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Podrías enseñarnos algo del código que ya tienes ? Es una buena forma de visualizar mejor cuál es tu problema.

Comment: La pregunta está demasiado amplia. Debes mostrarnos el código de lo que tienes hecho, además de el error que dices que te da

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, pues lo pudieras solucionar creando un nuevo Type, digamos:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\EntityToIntTransformer;

class EntityIdType extends AbstractType
{

    private $om;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new EntityToIntTransformer($this->om, $options['data_class']);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);

//        $transformer = new EntityToIntTransformer(
//                $this->om, $options['data_class']
//        );

        //$builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'La entidad no existe.'
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType::class;
    }

}
```

Lo registras como servicio

```
services:
    app.form.type.entity_id:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\EntityIdType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - {name: form.type, alias: entity_id }
```

y en el formulario pues lo empleas como un widget más.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $form->add('embarazada', EntityIdType::class, array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\EntityConcreta',
        'empty_data' => null
    ));
}
```